# Visual Odometry in opencv (possibly using RGBD)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am attempting to implement a visual odometry solution in opencv, and running into a few problems. This is quite a broad question, so I apologise in advance, however I have a number of questions.

My understanding of the problem currently is:
Obtain some model to represent the correspondence between two successive images, be that optical flow or feature matching. 
Obtain the fundamental (and then essential if needed) matrix from these point correspondences. 
Calculate [R|t] from that.

I am aware of the findFundamentalMat function in openCV, but I think that only takes 2D point matches? In Scaramuzza and Fraundorfers paper 'Visual Odometry - pt1' they suggest that 3-D to 2-D correspondences will be most accurate.

I guess then my question is can I use the depth data retrieved from a kinect, giving me 3-D feature points, be used in opencv to give me an egomotion estimation?

I've also taken a look at solvePnP, but as far as I'm aware this only solves for a single frame (for when you know the real model space coordinates of features, like with a fiducial marker)
Although I did consider if I track 3D points between two frames, solving the perspective in the first frame, then in the second frame with the same points should give me a transformation between the two?

I apologize for this badly formulated question, I am still new to computer vision. Rather than attempting to answer this question if it is too much of a minefield, I would be appreciative of a point to any related literature or opencv tutorials for odometry. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example rgbdodometry.cpp in opencv\samples\cpp folder.
Have you seen it?

Comment: Yes, I was going to tag that on, but my question was already diluted enough! From reading the corresponding paper, it seems to use some kind of dense energy minimisation approach, which seems to work, albeit a little bit slow. 
I'm trying to implement a sparse solution, with feature matches and compare the speeds.

Comment: Ok, I am apologize for misunderstanding of you problem. The best SLAM solution I've tested is EKF Mono SLAM by Javier Civera: http://webdiis.unizar.es/~jcivera/code/1p-ransac-ekf-monoslam.html but it doesn't use depth component, and implemented in MATLAB. There are also several papers of this author on the site. Also good resource about SLAM (including RGBD-SLAM) you can find on site: https://openslam.org/

Comment: Thanks for link, I think I've read the paper on this, but never found the source so I'll try this out. Hopefully be able to come back with a more formulated question later in time!

Comment: @AndreySmorodov Can you tell me how to execute the rgbdodometry.cpp in the opencv samples? I am new to cpp and am having trouble in compilation.

Comment: There is help in source file lines 83-88. And you need set vals[] array, as camera matrix.